# Stopping my python loop for a game I made

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to make a board game in Python. It's my very first project.

It needs to be cleaned up, but before I do that, I'd like to have the basic things working, which includes stopping the game.

After all of the properties have been bought, the game just goes into an infinite loop.

What I am trying to do: Once all of the properties have been purchased, stop the game. Winner is the player with the most funds.

```
#IMPORTING STATEMENTS
from random import random
from random import randint

#DEFINE BOARD SIZE
board_size = 20

#PLAYERS
#Creating the players
num_players = 4

#Player funds for each player
player_funds = [250] * num_players

#players starting positions for each player
players_position = [0] * num_players


#PROPERTY
#Prices, rent(20%), category (3 properties of each length of square board), owner
property_prices = {
    "Property 1": {"cost": 100, "rent": 20, "category": "Category 1", 'owner': None},
    "Property 2": {"cost": 150, "rent": 30, "category": "Category 1", 'owner': None},
    "Property 3": {"cost": 200, "rent": 40, "category": "Category 1", 'owner': None},
    "Property 4": {"cost": 250, "rent": 50, "category": "Category 2", 'owner': None},
    "Property 5": {"cost": 200, "rent": 40, "category": "Category 2", 'owner': None},
    "Property 6": {"cost": 120, "rent": 24, "category": "Category 2", 'owner': None},
    "Property 7": {"cost": 200, "rent": 40, "category": "Category 3", 'owner': None},
    "Property 8": {"cost": 180, "rent": 36, "category": "Category 3", 'owner': None},
    "Property 9": {"cost": 100, "rent": 20, "category": "Category 3", 'owner': None},
    "Property 10": {"cost": 150, "rent": 30, "category": "Category 4", 'owner': None},
    "Property 11": {"cost": 200, "rent": 40, "category": "Category 4", 'owner': None},
    "Property 12": {"cost": 200, "rent": 40, "category": "Category 4", 'owner': None},
}

#property ownership as per board size
property_ownership = [-1] * board_size

#category_ownership = category[player]

#CREATING THE DICE
#creating a function to roll the dice
def roll_dice():
    return randint(1,6)


#EFFECTS
effect_tiles = ['Go forward 2 spaces',
                 'Go forward 3 spaces',
                 'Gain 50',
                 'Pay 10 in fees',
                 'Go to start and gain 50',
                 'Roll again']

#Effects functions
def effect_function(player, players_position):
    #establish effect index with players position relative to board size
    effect_index = players_position[player] % board_size
    #establish the effect for the index
    effect = effect_tiles[effect_index]

#Create statements for each effect
    if effect == 'Go forward 2 spaces':
        players_position[player] += 2
    elif effect == 'Go forward 3 spaces':
        players_position[player] += 3
    elif effect == 'Gain 50':
        player_funds[player] += 50
    elif effect == 'Pay 10 in fees':
        player_funds[player] -= 10
    elif effect == 'Go to start and gain 50':
        players_position[player] = 0
        player_funds[player] += 50
    elif effect == 'Roll again':
        return True
    
    print(f'Player {player+1} landed on an effects tile: {effect}')


#THE GAME ----

#define current players position
current_player = 0

#The loop
while True:
#Iterating over each player
    #define players and rolls
    player = current_player % num_players
    #roll the dice, ensuring rolls are < 3
    
    dice_roll = roll_dice()

    #update the players position appropriate to board size
    players_position[player] += dice_roll
    players_position[player] %= board_size
        
    #if player >19 places on the board size, reset to 0 and give 50
    if players_position[player] == 0:
        player_funds[player] += 50

    #if a player lands on an effects tile
    if players_position[player] < len(effect_tiles):
        #effect_function(player, players_position)
        roll_again = effect_function(player, players_position)

        if roll_again:
            rolls = 1
            while rolls <3:
                dice_roll = roll_dice()
                players_position[player] += dice_roll
                players_position[player] %= board_size
                
                if players_position[player] < len(effect_tiles):
                    roll_again = effect_function(player, rolls, players_position)

                    if not roll_again:
                        break

                rolls +=1


    #Checking if a player lands on a property
    property_index = players_position[player]
    property_name = f'Property {property_index + 1}'

    #IF A PROPERTY IS OWNED
    if property_name in property_prices and property_ownership[property_index] == 0:
        #decipher ownership
        if property_ownership[property_index] != player:
            owner = property_ownership[property_index]
            #define rent amount
            property_rent = property_prices[property_name]["rent"]

            #check if a player owns all properties in a category
            category = property_prices[property_name]['category']
            category_properties = [prop for prop in property_prices if property_prices[prop]['category'] == category]
            owns_all_in_category = all(property_ownership[property_ownership[player]] == player for prop in category_properties)
            
            #if owns all in one category, doulbe the rent
            if owns_all_in_category:
                property_rent*2
                print(f'Rent has doubled.')
            else:
                property_rent

            #pay rent
            player_funds[player] -= property_rent
            player_funds[owner] += property_rent
            
            #Update the display with rent paid, and new fund amount
            print(f'Player {player+1}: You have paid Player{owner+1} {property_rent} in rent. You now have {player_funds[player]}.')
            print(f'Player{owner+1}, you now have {player_funds[owner]}.')


#IF A PROPERTY IS UNOWNED
    if property_name in property_prices and property_ownership[property_index] == -1:
    #Ask the player if they would like to purchase the property
        #define property cost at appropriate index
        property_cost = property_prices[property_name]["cost"]
        #property_cost = property_prices[property_name]["cost"]
        purchase_choice = input(f'Player {player+1}, you have landed on an unowned property at {property_index+1}\n'
                        f'This property costs {property_cost}. You have {player_funds[player]}. Do you want to buy it? (y/n)')
        
        if purchase_choice.lower() == 'y':
        #Check the player has enough money to buy
            #if player has enough money:
            if player_funds[player] >= property_cost:
                #deduct from players funds
                player_funds[player] -= property_cost
                #update ownership
                property_ownership[property_index] = player
                #update owner value
                property_prices[property_name]['owner'] = player
                #confirm the property has been bought
                print(f'You have purchased {property_name}')
            #if not enough money
            else:
                print('You do not have enough money to purchase this property.')
        
    
    #display the player, dice roll and current position
    print(f"Player {player+1}: Your current position is {players_position[player]}. You have {player_funds[player]}")
    #Make display easier to navigate & ready
    print('-')
    #update current player
    current_player += 1
    
    #Kicking players out of the game
    #If a player has no more money
    if player_funds[player] < 0:
        print(f'Player {player+1} is out of money and has been removed from the game.')

        #set properties as unowned
        for prop in category_properties:
            #accessing the property index and splitting it
            property_index = int(prop.split()[1]) -1
            property_ownership[property_index] = None

        #remove player from game
        del player_funds[player]
        del players_position[player]
        num_players -= 1
        current_player -=1

        #check if there is one player left (the winner)
        if num_players == 1:
            winner = player_funds.index(max(player_funds))
            print(f'Player {winner+1} has won! with {player_funds[player]} in their bank!')
            

    #WINNING CONDITIONS
    if all(property_ownership[index] != -1 for index in range(board_size)):
        print('All properties are owned. You have 10 rounds. The player with the most money at the end, wins')

        #End the game and determine winner
        max_money = player_funds[player]
        winners = [i + 1 for i, fund in enumerate(player_funds) if fund == max_money]
        if len(winners)== 1:
            print(f'Player {winners[0]} wins the game with {player_funds[winners[0]]}')
            print('Player {player+1} ended with {player_funds[player]}')
        else:
            print(f'Its a tie.')
            break

#The end.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `while true`, you could use a variable, like `running`:

```
running = True
while running:
    ...
```

Then when you want the game to end, you can just set `running = False`.

```
if len(winners)== 1:
    running = False
```

Edit:
I have a few suggestions, when I was looking through your code,

- you seem to have `player` and `current_player` doing the same thing, or at least it is difficult to see the logic.
  I suggest using `current_player` and at the start of each loop you set the `current_player` and do all calculations in reference to them:

:

```
#update current player
current_player += 1
current_player %= num_players
```

- `property_prices` could just be a list, and when you want `property_name` you could use `"Property" + str(property_index + 1)`
- The roll checking if the dice has been rolled up to 3 times could be simplified with something like:

:

```
#if a player lands on an effects tile
if players_position[current_player] < len(effect_tiles):
    rolls = 1
    while players_position[current_player] < len(effect_tiles) and rolls < 3:
        effect_function(current_player, players_position)
        dice_roll = roll_dice()
        players_position[current_player] += dice_roll
        players_position[current_player] %= board_size
        rolls +=1
```

- You might be able to use `'owner': None` in `property_prices` to set ownership, and it saves using the data structure `property_ownership = [-1] * board_size`.

Feel free to discard this if I misinterpreted.

Comment: Thank you @tok1n. Your answer helped for the code with kicking a player out and ending the game, however the loop continues and no winner is determined when players are still in the game and all properties are purchased

Comment: In `if num_players == 1:` then?

Comment: I think the problem lies in how I've defined category_properties, but Im not sure how to rewrite it.

Comment: I can't understand... are the first 6 squares effects? Then there are also 12 properties, the first 12? Is it an infinite loop because landing on the effects means you never sell those properties?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I solved it now. The issue was in the indexing when kicking players out, so the game couldn't decipher ownership correctly. Also had to redefine the property_index definition. You answer was the most helpful so marked as solved

Comment: No problem. I added some comments to the answer, which i thought of when I was looking through it, but feel free to discard them, just thought it might help.

Answer (score 0):

Property index never returns as 1 or 5. And because:

```
property_name = f'Property {property_index + 1}'
```

Properties 2 and 6 are not purchasable.